# Error while deploying a theme which is .lpkg file in liferay 6.2 ga5

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.2 ga5 when i am trying to deploy themes which is a .lpkg file from control panel->App Manager->Install->Browse .i am facing the below error

Error:
4:23:44,405 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-4][SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:630] Reject process action for http://localhost:8080/group/control_panel/manage on 3_WAR_marketplaceportlet

Can anyone please provide a solution to fix this error.Thanks in advance

Comment: You might have more luck on the liferay forums. Stackoverflow is for programming-related questions and this seems quite far from that topic.

Comment: [Continued here](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/77519292).